# How to pass html through a php variable into jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm just taking my first steps with js/jquery, and I was trying to reload the content of a table using jquery but I'm not figuring out how:

```
if(isset($_POST['mode']) && $_POST['mode'] == "toggleactive"){

    $admin = new funcadmin($dbo);

    if($admin->toggleState($_POST['id_users'])){

        $table = $admin->getUsers();
        echo json_encode($table); //??????
    }
    else{
        $erroruser = 'Erro!';
        echo json_encode($erroruser);
    }
}
```

and on the view:

```
<table id="userlist">    
<?php echo $table; ?> //How I load the original table

</table>
<script>
    function toggleState(id_users){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin.php",
            data: {id_users:id_users, mode:"toggleactive"},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(table) {
             $("#userlist").innerhtml('table');
            },
            error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
            }
        });
    }</script>
```

Many thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Baya

Comment: what's the error you're facing? also in your success handler, you need to pass the variable `table` not the string (just a note).

Comment: Did you just mean to use the *variable* "table" instead of the *literal string* "table"?:  `$("#userlist").innerhtml(table);`

Comment: Baya give mor details

Comment: Hi, have you tried 'echoing' your PHP as in a script tag: `<script>const table = <?php echo $table ?>;</script>`

Comment: The function updates the db correctly, but then instead of updating the table I get an alert saying "[object Object]"

Comment: And yes David, I'm trying to pass the content of a variable

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar : on the controller I get a $table variable which holds a set of table rows which I'm trying to pass back to jquery, so it replaces the content of the #userlist table with the new content

Comment: @Baya: *"I get an alert saying "[object Object]""* - Do you mean that your `error` callback is being invoked?  Then examine what the actual error is.  You should use `console.log` instead of `alert`.  Check your browser's debugging tools.  See what's logged to the console, see what is being returned by the server, etc.  You have to find out what the error *is* before you can correct it.

Comment: @David: I guess this would be it "statusText
:
"parsererror"", but I'm not understanding why that is

Comment: any suggestion on what it might be?

Comment: @Baya: What is the actual response being returned from the server?  Is it valid JSON?  Something else?

Comment: echo json_encode($table); I'm sorry if I'm getting this wrong, but I'm passing a variable ($table) containing a set of table rows into json_encode, which I assume it encodes it into valid JSON, right?

Comment: @Baya: *"which I assume..."* - Stop assuming and start debugging.  Use your browser's debugging tools to observe the *actual* response coming back from the server.  Press F12 in your browser to open the debugging tools.  (Assuming your browser has this.  If it doesn't, use one that does such as Chrome.)

Comment: The response header cache-control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-type:application/json
date:Thu, 08 Feb 2018 14:20:38 GMT
expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:Apache
status:200
x-powered-by:PHP/7.1.14

Comment: Also, on the preview and reponse tabs in the network tab I see the updated table where it should be, but on the actual page nothing changes

Comment: i need to know your `$admin->getUsers();` function what is the return of this? is it a table or object?

Comment: Greetings Dee, it's a table, more precisely a string with a set of table rows. Didnt think to make it an object since from what I've read regarding json_encode it would convert any value into json compatible

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with JQuery properly.
The problem was here:
if($admin->toggleState($_POST['id_users']))

I never told the function to return true, was kind of expecting that the return of the ->execute() to be enough. Now that I did its all working well.

My sincere applologies for your lost time, and thank you all for all the help you were willing to give.

Cheers,
Baya